# PostgreSQL Trigger Before Insert For Each Statement

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I would like to know if **PosgreSQL** (12) can fire a **trigger before insert**, **for each statement** (for performance issues)? If so, how to access (actually change) the rows to be inserted, from inside the triggered function?

I am thinking of something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_process() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP IN ('UPDATE', 'INSERT') THEN
        UPDATE new_table 
        SET field_to_set = other_table.field
        FROM other_table
        WHERE new_table.id_to_other_table = other_table.id ;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_process_ins
    BEFORE INSERT ON temp
    REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION tr_process();
CREATE TRIGGER tr_process_upd
    BEFORE UPDATE ON temp
    REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table NEW TABLE AS new_table
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION tr_process();
```

This is currently kicking me an `ERROR:  transition table name can only be specified for an AFTER trigger`.

I tried a `for each row` trigger, but the cost is so much more expensive than, for instance, simply including an `INNER JOIN` statement in the `INSERT` statement to have a proper `field_to_set`.

I am looking at a `BEFORE` trigger as I expect the new value of `field_to_set` to raise a uniqueness constraint, if relevant.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The error message says it all, you cannot have transition tables in a `BEFORE` trigger. But I see no reason in your code why that couldn't be an `AFTER` trigger.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Because I assume that in an `AFTER` trigger, my rows have already been inserted in the table, and it's too late for my updated `field_to_change` to potentially raise a uniqueness constraint anymore?

Comment: If the trigger causes an exception, all changes to the table will be undone, because the trigger always runs in the same transaction as the statement.

Comment: A Statement trigger does not see the actual rows which are changed. A statement trigger is fired no matter if something changes or not - you could have 0 updated/deleted rows and still the trigger fires.

Comment: +1 on this. I've been looking for an answer as well. The best I've found so far is `AFTER` update can use `REFERENCING OLD TABLE old_table` and then do some sql jockeying to get the information. But it's still not a solution to your need.